# SQL: Mege two rows in one

Tags: mysql, sql

On MySQL I'd like to merge 2 rows in 1, for example:

```
| Name | Value | Res |
| foo  | Type  | 0.2 |
| foo  | Group | aaa |
| bar  | Type  | 0.3 |
| bar  | Group | bbb |
```

my expected result would be:

```
| Name | Type   | Group |
| foo  |  0.2   |  aaa  |
| bar  |  0.3   |  bbb  |
```

I'd like to merge two entries with some common values in one that has two column that distinct a value in a `Res` column on the value of a `Type` column. How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why would a value of type1 appear in column called type?

Comment: @P.Salmon, yeh you're right it was a bit confusing, now I've corrected the question. Thanks

Comment: Do you only have 2 distinct values or are there lots and you are only using 2 as an example?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have about 1'000'000 of values, now I've solved with an `INNER JOIN` on same table but it take too much

Comment: But the values will only ever be type or group?

Comment: No, but those are the only two value in which I are interested in, so I filtered the table before. The table is a bit more complex but this is a representative example

Answer (score 3):

Your expect result need to do pivot try to use *condition aggregate function* to make it.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Name varchar(50),
     Value varchar(50),
     Res varchar(50)
);



insert into t values ( 'foo' ,'Type' , '0.2');
insert into t values ( 'foo' ,'Group' , 'aaa');
insert into t values ( 'bar' ,'Type' , '0.3');
insert into t values ( 'bar' ,'Group' , 'bbb');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Value= 'Type'  THEN Res END) Type,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Value= 'Group 'THEN Res END) `Group` 
FROM T
GROUP BY Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7aa8c/2/0)**:

```
| Name | Type | Group |
|------|------|-------|
|  bar |  0.3 |   bbb |
|  foo |  0.2 |   aaa |
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer from [Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47861/how-to-join-two-result-sets-to-query-on-output-came-from-two-statements) - should be very useful.

To do this you will need to run two sub-queries, and then combine the results with a JOIN command.

Assuming your table is called T:

```
SELECT s.`Name`, s.`type`, p.`group`
FROM 
(
  SELECT `Name`, `Res` as `type`
  FROM T  WHERE `Value`="type1"
) s
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT `Name`, `Res` as `group`
  FROM T
  WHERE `Value`="group1"
) p
ON s.`Name` = p.`Name`
```

I know that your example had the variable names changed for ease of reading - but be careful with your choices as they may be reserved words in MySQL.

This can be seen in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54d679/7)

Comment: Yes, actually I do a join on same table but with about 1'000'000 of records it take a lot of time

Comment: @NickF_93 if that's the case and if this query is frequently accessed, you should consider normalize Type and Group to a separate table.